solve a Number CAPTCHA with opencv and tensorflow
I am working on a project where I use OpenCV for image preprocessing. Below is my code for preprocessing the image:
def preprocess_with_opencv(img):
    img = img.numpy()

    # Resize
    img = cv2.resize(img, (img_width, img_height), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    # GaussianBlur
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)

    # Adaptive Threshold
    img = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        img, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2
    )

    # Chuẩn hóa
    img = img.astype("float32") / 255.0
    img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)

    return img

After preprocessing, I use the following function to encode the image for further processing:
def encode_single_sample(img_path, label):
    # 1. Đọc ảnh
    img = tf.io.read_file(img_path)

    # 2. Decode ảnh (grayscale)
    img = tf.io.decode_png(img, channels=1)

    # 3. Sử dụng OpenCV để xử lý trước
    img = tf.py_function(preprocess_with_opencv, [img], Tout=tf.float32)

    # 4. Transpose nếu mô hình yêu cầu
    img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])

    # 5. Trả về dictionary (image, label)
    return {"image": img, "label": label}

The original image looks like this:

However, after processing the image using the encode_single_sample function, the data seems incorrect, and the output image is not clear. How can I resolve this issue and ensure that the processed image is accurate and clear?

It might be something to do with the line of code
img = tf.transpose(img, perm=[1, 0, 2])

in encode_single_sample function.
I ran the code and checked the output by using matplotlib's matshow() function and it seemed the image was the same but was rotated by 90 degrees. Check the order of the matrix that you want for your input node and transpose the image matrix accordingly.
